# Strange TextBox behavior in Windows 8.1 and windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf

The following code works like expected in Windows 7:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="Auto"
    Width="500"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" 
    SizeToContent="Height" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True"
             MinLines="6"
             MaxLines="6" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             Text="test &#10;test &#10;test &#10;test &#10;test &#10;test &#10;test &#10;test &#10;test &#10;"/>
</Grid>
```

The same code running under Win8.1 or Win10 shows the TextBox with its vertical scrollbar centered vertically within a larger TextBox area.

It seems to be a WPF layout problem. The code was developed in VS2013, .net 4.5. All tested windows systems are x64.
Any ideas to make this simple app running with same results in win7 ... win10?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line

```
MaxLines="6"
```

it is causing your `Textbox` to be limited in height and appear vertically centered in `Window`

Comment: Removing MaxLines would not limit the size of the TextBox which is required in my app. Also it does not explain the reason why this code runs correctly in Win7 and not in Win 8.1 or 10.

Comment: Use `VerticalAlignment="Center"` or any other relevant value.

Comment: VerticalAlignment or VerticalContentAlignment does not change anything in this example. The only property, that changes the visual result, is the VerticalScrollBarVisibility set to "Auto". In that case the scrollbar is only visible if there are more than 6 lines of text in the TextBox, which is not the same when setting it to "Visible".

Comment: Please put some backgroud color on the `Window`, then you'll see that when you have no `VerticalAlignment` or set it to `Stratch`, there is a big `TextBox` with only scrollbars in the center, but when you set `VerticalAlignment to `Center`, the TextBox is small.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but the VerticalAlignment property does not change anything here. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to upload images. Here now 2 links that show the different visual representations of the same code under Win7 and Win8.1 or Win10 to show the problem. Win7: [link](http://s29.postimg.org/q3pt56m3b/Text_Box1_W7.jpg) and Win8.1: [link](http://s9.postimg.org/66pyzyui7/Text_Box1_W8.jpg)